# when was require("which") born?

Tags: node.js, native-code

Just noticed I can use a module called `which` in nodejs 6.x. `require("which")`. But cannot find docs to this native module. Can some one tell where the docs are and at which version of node the module was introduced?

Comment: `which` does not appear to be a built in module: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPy73IR6aNJeLxGE579ql3UvTvZSDFss_E

Comment: hmm I use v6.3.0 It seems this is answered then :)

Comment: hmm . I figured out you cannot require in console. but I use it in an index.js and run node ```index.js```

Comment: var fs = require('fs')
    var path = require('path')
    var which = require('which')
    var pm2_path = fs.realpathSync(which.sync('pm2'))
    pm2_path = path.join(pm2_path, "..", "node_modules", "pm2", "index.js" );
    console.log(pm2_path);
    var pm2 = require(pm2_path);
    console.log(pm2);

Comment: Doesn't work in 6.3.0 even when I put it in a script: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOq-ZTVYgpEkpuuFq8ss1IYY9VDjQ42foo

Comment: weird. My folder is empty just contains an index.js file :/

Answer (score 0):

`which` is not a built-in module even in Node 6.3.0.

Presumably you have installed it [from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which) using the `-g` flag to install it globally.

Comment: We cannot require global installed modules. Its the reason I want to use which :)